# C# A problem with casting

Tags: c#, casting

I have that code:

`myDataGrid` is an object passed to the method. I know it is type of `OvserveableCollection` of different types.
All I need is to cast that object to `OvserveableCollection<T>` (it implements the `IEnumerable` interface)

```
//get element's type
Type entryType = (myDataGrid as IEnumerable).AsQueryable().ElementType; 

foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<entryType>)myDataGrid)
{}
```

but the compiler doesn't know the `entryType` in the loop header. Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a runtime `Type` instance as a generic type parameter unless you use reflection (`MakeGenericMethod()` / `MakeGenericType()`). However I doubt it would help anyway! In this scenario, either use the non-generic `IEnumerable` (no `<T>`) API, or perhaps cast to a known interface/subclass, or use `dynamic` as a last resort duck-typing.

You *can* also use `MakeGenericMethod()` etc, but that is more involved and almost certainly slower.

For example:

```
foreach(object item in (IEnumerable)myDataGrid)
{
     // tada!
}
```

Another trick can be to use `dynamic` to invoke the generic code:

```
public void Iterate<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
     foreach(T item in data) {...}
}
...
dynamic evil = myDataGrid;
Iterate(evil);
```

Comment: I didn't know about the new `dynamic` type. And, yes, it's evil, and therefore I think I'm going to love it. Once a script-bunny, allways a hacker. Thanks for the fish ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use a `Type` *variable* as a type argument for a generic type. Generics don't work that way - you have to use a compile-time type as the type argument. (That compile-time type can be a type parameter itself, if you're doing this in a generic method.)

It's hard to know how to advise you to change the code without knowing more about your requirements though - what do you need to do with the items?

Comment: I need to iterate through that ObserveableCollection to read the data in each element

Comment: @Tony: You can do that just as `object` though - why do you need a more specific compile-time type?

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast to a "runtime type"... in order to "write" the instructions which actually implement that cast, the compiler requires the Type... which really just means that the Type must be known at COMPILE time.

The ONLY way I've ever found around this limitation was code-generator (of one sort or another) to "manually" generate the IL instructions to perform the cast. It's hard to know what to recommend unless we know a lot about your actual requirements (and constraints).

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Yeah... unfortunately I'm busily upgrading our apps to 3.5, coz 4.0 wasn't out when we started this round of insanity... Sigh.